# Coproduct of rooted posets

Tags: category-theory

## The questions

Currently, I'm working with "Category Theory" by Steve Awodey (which is quite readable, by the way). Their, on page 68 he gives an example for a coproduct, the coproduct in *rooted* posets:

> [Somewhere before] we considered the coproduct of rooted posets $P$ and $Q$ by first making $P+Q$ [(in posets)] and then "identifying" the resulting two different $0_P$ and $0_Q$ [...]. We can now describe this "identification" as a coequalizer taken in posets.

The coequalizer is the following:

> 1 ==($0_P,0_Q$)==> P+Q --$e$--> P+Q/($0_P$ = $0_Q$).

Regarding this setup I have two questions:

1. How can I prove, that $P\rightarrow P+Q/(0_P = 0_Q) \leftarrow Q$ is a coproduct in rooted posets?
2. Does $1$ play a special role here or could I've come up with any object?

## Own ideas so far

First, let $C = P+Q/(0_P = 0_Q)$ and let the rest of the names like in the following diagram:

[image: The situation as a diagram]

For the morphisms $P \rightarrow C$ and $Q \rightarrow C$ I picked $e\circ i_P$ and $e\circ i_Q$, which means that I have to show that for any rooted poset $Z$ and $z_P, z_Q$, there exists a unique morphism $u_C : C \rightarrow Z$ such that $z_P = u_C\circ e \circ i_P$ and $z_Q = u_C\circ e \circ i_Q$. Since $P\rightarrow P+Q \leftarrow Q$ is a coproduct in posets there is a unique $u_{P+Q} : P+Q \rightarrow Z$ such that

$$z_P = i_P\circ u_{P+Q} \text{$\;$  and  $\;$} z_Q = i_Q\circ u_{P+Q}.$$

If there is the chance to prove that $u_{P+Q}\circ 0_P = u_{P+Q}\circ 0_Q$ then the coequalizer UMP gives me all I need, since $e$ has to be unique by the coproduct property already. But I might be to close to see a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the morphisms of rooted posets are morphisms of "normal" posets preserving the root.

"The root" is most conveniently thought of as a morphism $0_P^P: 1 \to P$ in this case. $1$, the terminal object, is quite important here, because morphisms out of it can be seen as "elements" -- in this case because both in $\sf Pos$ and $\sf Pos^*$ it is the singleton poset.

Then we have for $0_P^{P+Q} := 0_P: 1 \to P+Q$ that it decomposes as $i_P0_P^P$; similarly for $Q$.

Thus: $$u_{P+Q}0_P^{P+Q} = u_{P+Q}i_P0_P^P = z_P0_P^P = 0_Z\\u_{P+Q}0_Q^{P+Q} = u_{P+Q}i_Q0_Q^Q = z_Q0_Q^Q = 0_Z$$

(Note that you wrote the composition for the UMP for $u_{P+Q}$ the wrong way around.)

Comment: Thanks. I'm always struggling when I have to look into the category... Here that $I_P \circ 0_P^P = 0_P$ in Pos*.